# highlighting search results using Postgresql GIN/GiST

Tags: postgresql, full-text-search, search-engine, highlight

Is there a built in way of highlighting matched search keywords when using Postgresql's GIN or GiST index? Or if not, a way of doing this outside Postgresql?

I'm using PHP 5.3.10 and Postgresql 9.1.3.

All ideas are appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look on ts_headline function [ts_headline](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/interactive/textsearch-controls.html#TEXTSEARCH-HEADLINE).

```
SELECT ts_headline('english',
  'The most common type of search
is to find all documents containing given query terms
and return them in order of their similarity to the
query.',
  to_tsquery('query & similarity'));
                        ts_headline                         
------------------------------------------------------------
 containing given <b>query</b> terms
 and return them in order of their <b>similarity</b> to the
 <b>query</b>.
```